# arabic fonts in Laravel pdf file issue

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, fonts, arabic

For generating pdf files in my Laravel app, I used `niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf` package that it supports arabic language, No I want add custom fonts, I followed the [documentation](https://github.com/niklasravnsborg/laravel-pdf#custom-fonts) but it's not working, the text was showin with the default font of the package (I don't know what is..)
this is config/pdf.php :

```
...
    'font_path' => base_path('/resources/fonts/'),
    'font_data' => [
            'NotoKufiArabic' => [
                'R'  => 'NotoKufiArabic-VariableFont_wght.ttf',    // regular font // I tried also NotoKufiArabic-Regular
                'B'  => 'NotoKufiArabic-Bold.ttf',       // optional: bold font
                'I'  => 'NotoKufiArabic-Medium.ttf',     // optional: italic font
                'BI' => 'NotoKufiArabic-SemiBold.ttf' ,// optional: bold-italic font
                'useOTL' => 0xFF,    // required for complicated langs like Persian, Arabic and Chinese
                'useKashida' => 75,  // required for complicated langs like Persian, Arabic and Chinese
            ]
            // ...add as many as you want.
        ]
```

css code in blade :

```
 body {
            font-family: "NotoKufiArabic", sans-serif;
        }
```

and I added `.ttf` files in fonts directory like this 
[image]